# How to change an image property based on screen size?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change a background image size from "cover" to "contain" based on the screen size.

I currently have:

```
style="background-image: url('images/hbc/slider-3.webp'); background-size: cover;"
```

I want to change it to `background-size: contain;` for phones only.

I have tried everything I thought might make sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet, and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Comment: Use Media query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have now

```css
.block-img{
    background-image: url('images/hbc/slider-3.webp'); 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

you need

```css
@media(max-width:768px){
    .block-img{
        background-size:contain;
    }
}
```

When the screen becomes less than 768 pixels (for phones), this block will change its property `cover` to `contain`.